# SQL Spatial DWithin

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a SQL Server 2008 SQL Spatial equivalent to PostGIS DWithin? I have two linestrings that appear to come together at a single point, but it must be that they are just off because STIntersect says they do not intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html: "ST_DWithin(geometry, geometry, float) Returns true if geometries are within the specified distance of one another. Uses indexes if available."

The equivalent SQL Server method for:
ST_DWithin(geomA, geomB, d)

would therefore be:
geomA.STDistance(geomB) < d